# Length of a matcher in Java

Tags: java, matcher

I have to extract words from a string, but only if they are at least two chars long. I have to use regex. The code works, but for all kind of words. What should I use? Here`s my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class P5_ExtractWords {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String text = input.nextLine();
        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z]+");
        Matcher match = pat.matcher(text);
        while (match.find()){
            System.out.printf("%s ",match.group());
        }
        input.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I can`t find a method for matcher`s length or something like this.

Answer (score 3):

I will use something like this in your regular expression.

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z][A-Za-z]+");
```

With this pattern, the first part of the rule will be true when you have one char and the second when you have one ore more chars. This pattern is expressed in a general regular expression way. You can use other types of rules like the others provided in different answers.

Answer (score 3):

The pattern:

> `Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z]+");`

Means one or more `[A-Za-z]` characters.

For two or more, you can use the form:

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\\w{2,}");
```

The pattern `\w` is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

Or

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z]{2,}");
```

For only letters.

Answer (score 0):

Length of characters to be matched

`{n,m}  n <= length <= m
 {n}    length == n
 {n,}   length >= n`

```
`^\w{0,10}$ # allows words of up to 10 characters.
```

`^\w{2,}$   # allows words of more than 2 characters.`

`^\w{5,10}$ # allows words of between 5 and 10 characters.`

If you want to use word boundaries use `\b` in your regular expression.

Since it's Java, you'll actually have to escape the backslashes: "\\w{1,10}\\b". You probably knew this already, but it's gotten me before.
I hope this [Link](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9781449327453/ch04s09.html) might helpful.